# Swift SKAction moveTo bottom of screen

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I am trying to make my two sprite nodes to fall from the top of the screen to the bottom of the screen, move back to their starting position and then fall again, however at the moment when they reach about 3/4 of the way down the screen, they get 'teleported' up the screen slightly and from there they continue to fall before being 'teleported' back up a little more, eventually they fall off the bottom of the screen as expected. Here is what I have:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    height = bounds.size.height

    initFruit()
    fallTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.2, target: self, selector: "fall_timer", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func initFruit(){

    fruit1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Fruit_Apple")
    fruit2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Fruit_Banana")

    fruit1.xScale = 2.5
    fruit1.yScale = 2.5
    fruit2.xScale = 2.5
    fruit2.yScale = 2.5

    //position fruit off the top of the screen, at separate x coordinates
    fruit1.position = CGPoint(x: (size.width / 3), y: height + fruit1.frame.height)
    fruit2.position = CGPoint(x: (size.width / 3) * 2, y: height + fruit1.frame.height)

    addChild(fruit1)
    addChild(fruit2)
}

func fall_timer() {
    var fallDuration: NSTimeInterval
    var moveActionDown: SKAction

    //If fruit are at the bottom, move them back up to the top
    if fruit1.position.y == -100 {
        fruit1.position.y = CGFloat(height + fruit1.frame.height)
        fruit2.position.y = CGFloat(height + fruit1.frame.height)
    }
    if fruit3.position.y == -100 {
        fruit3.position.y = CGFloat(height + fruit1.frame.height)
        fruit4.position.y = CGFloat(height + fruit1.frame.height)
    }

    //Check if fruit are at top, ready to fall again
    if fruit1.position.y == height + fruit1.frame.height {
        fallDuration = NSTimeInterval(arc4random_uniform(6) + 2)
        moveActionDown = SKAction.moveToY(-100.0, duration: fallDuration)
        fruit1.runAction(moveActionDown)
    }
    if fruit2.position.y == height + fruit1.frame.height {
        fallDuration = NSTimeInterval(arc4random_uniform(6) + 2)
        moveActionDown = SKAction.moveToY(-100.0, duration: fallDuration)
        fruit2.runAction(moveActionDown)
    }

}
```

I cannot for the life of me figure why this happens. It only does it on the first fall. After the first fall, the fruit fall perfectly and move back up to the top just as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just run an endless action on the fruit

```
let fall=SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([
    SKAction.moveToY(height, duration: 0),
    SKAction.moveToY(0, duration: 1)]))
```

and perhaps run a block when they reach the bottom

```
let fall=SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([
    SKAction.moveToY(height, duration: 0),
    SKAction.moveToY(0, duration: 1),
    SKAction.runBlock({ () -> Void in
            println("reached bottom")
        })]))
```